# Unable to telnet to localhost

Tags: linux, telnet, ports

While trying to telnet to localhost I get the below error

```
telnet localhost 32768
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Network is unreachable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run

netstat -ln

it will probably reveal that your server listens to 0.0.0.0, which only allows IPv4 to connect. If the software listens to :: (IPv6 ANY) instead, it will allow both IPv4 and IPv6 to connect unless it tells the kernel otherwise with socksetopt() call (See man ipv6(7) IPV6_V6ONLY)

Comment: Here is the output from netstat

Comment: I did not notice the error message in your initial request. It appears that the ipv6 support is not loaded on your system. "modprobe ipv6" should temporary solve this problem, however, your applications still needs to be restarted, and listen to :: and not 0.0.0.0

Comment: Sorry, missed to paste:
http://pastebin.com/XZeBTpcR

Comment: On that paste, you can see that all programs listens to 0.0.0.0 (IPv4). So IPv6 will not be able to connect. If programs listens to ::, both IPv4 and IPv6 should be able to connect. Please modprobe ipv6 and restart the services. (automatic loading of IPv6 is probably configured inside /etc/modprobe.d/ )